# egrep search if a word appears multiple times side by side

Tags: grep

I was looking for a way to use egrep in order to find "mybigsentencemybigsentence" in a file.

I am relatively new to egrep so the only way I found is

egrep "mybigsentencemybigsentence" myfile

but how can I search as we would do with a character set using the "+" operator (one or more times)?

Thanx a lot.

Comment: I'd say this should go to Unix, but there isn't a close option to move it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use POSIX-compatible regular expressions with `egrep` or `grep -E`:

```
# The test file
$ cat test
abcabc
abc

# Match exactly two occurrences of 'abc'
$ grep -E '(abc){2}' test
abcabc

# Match one ore more occurrences of 'abc'
$ grep -E '(abc)+' test
abcabc
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an addition to joschi's answer:
If you don't know *mybigsentence* but you want to search for arbitrary repeated strings of a minimum length (I assume a length of 10 characters in my example) you could do it with GNU `egrep` like this:

```
egrep -on '([a-z]{10,})\1' myfile
```

This will return the line number (`-n`) of the match and the match itself (`-o`) but not the whole line (which you would get without `-o`).

But that will only work with the GNU version of `grep`.